# How to replace aws profile with new temporary credential with Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, methods

I am writing a Python script that will use the .getsessiontoken() method and write the new temporary credentials to the aws credentials file at ~/.aws/credentials. The profile, in my case will be named [temp-token].

I can write to the file successfully, but then I thought, what if that profile already exists. I would have to find and replace subsequent lines after the profile name. I'm still new to Python and trying to understand what the problem is:

```
import os
import boto3 as b

mfa_serial_number = "arn:aws:iam::xxxxxxxxxxxx:mfa/your-iam-user-here"
mfa_otp = input("Enter your otp:" )

def get_sts(mfa_serial_number, mfa_otp):
    
    session = b.Session(profile_name='default', region_name='us-east-1')
    sts = session.client('sts')
    if mfa_serial_number is not None:
        response = sts.get_session_token(
            SerialNumber=mfa_serial_number, TokenCode=mfa_otp)
    else:
        response = sts.get_session_token()
    temp_credentials = response['Credentials']
    print(temp_credentials)
    token_reponse = ["[temp-token] \n", "aws_access_key_id = " + temp_credentials["AccessKeyId"], "\n", "aws_secret_access_key = " + temp_credentials["SecretAccessKey"],"\n", "aws_session_token = " + temp_credentials["SessionToken"],"\n"]
    # Look for the temp-token profile
    pfile = "[temp-token]"
    with open("/Users/YOUR USER/.aws/credentials", "r") as credentials:
     aws_credential_file = credentials.readlines()
     #print(aws_credential_file)
    for line in aws_credential_file:
         if line.find(pfile) != -1:
             print('Profile Exists!')
             #Prints the line number where the word was found
             profile_line = aws_credential_file.index(line)
             new_aws_access_key_line_num = profile_line + 1
             new_secret_access_key_line_num = profile_line + 2
             new_session_token_key_line_num = profile_line + 3
             print("its still working", profile_line)
             print(new_aws_access_key_line_num)
             aws_credential_file[new_aws_access_key_line_num] = "aws_access_key_id = " + temp_credentials["AccessKeyId"], "\n"
            #  aws_credential_file[new_secret_access_key_line_num] = "aws_secret_access_key = " + temp_credentials["SecretAccessKey"],"\n"
            #  aws_credential_file[new_session_token_key_line_num] = "aws_session_token = " + temp_credentials["SessionToken"],"\n"
             #print()
        

            
     
         else:
          aws_credential_file.writelines(token_reponse)
          credentials.close()
    

get_sts(mfa_serial_number, mfa_otp)
```

The error I get is:
its still working 3
4
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/YOUR USER/code/sts.py", line 49, in 
get_sts(mfa_serial_number, mfa_otp)
File "/Users/YOUR USER/code/sts.py", line 29, in get_sts
if line.find(pfile) != -1:
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'find'

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the `,\n` in aws_credential_file